# MySQL cumulative some over months with gaps

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm trying to build a cumulative sum over months for the following table ;

```
created_at          Installs    port
2011-02-01 00:00:00    2        7033
2012-02-05 00:00:00    8        7032
2012-03-01 00:00:00    1        7031
2012-05-05 00:00:00    2        8500
2012-06-01 00:00:00    4        7545
```

I use the following query ;

```
SELECT
    created_at,
    Installs,
    @total := @total + Installs AS cumulative
FROM
table, (SELECT @total:=0) AS t
```

This works fine but for the months where there are no records, I get no sum.
I would like to fill the gaps with the last 'known' value.

My guess would be that I'd need to create a temporary table referencing each month of the year and then join on it, but I can't figure that out properly.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your guess is one way to handle this.

Create a (temporary or even better: permanent) table that has one row per month, say with the last day of every month. Then use `LEFT` join, with something like:

```
FROM 
        month_table AS mo 
    LEFT JOIN 
        table AS ta 
            ON  LAST_DAY(ta.created_at) = mo.last_day
```

---

Another thing that you should really take care if you want your query to be working fine - and not just fine by chance - is to add an ordering. Always use `ORDER BY` when you want the table to be processed some order - and "cumultive sum" suggests you don't want a randopm order. The DBMS will not always choose the same order, unless you specify so.